# Распределение ежемесячных чисел взрывов

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подпись к рисунку. Можно ли так говорить? Смущает сочетание "чисел взрывов".

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно, если текст технический и под "числами" там понимают какой-то специальный термин (как в термодинамике, например). Но я сильно сомневаюсь, что это так для данного текста.
В обычной же речи слово ***"числа"*** обычно тяготеет к ***единственному числу*** (простите, не могу иначе сказать), Sibylla верно пишет.

Еще точнее тут будет сказать "количество", но это скорее всего натолкнется на еще большее противодействие.

> Эх, мне нужно переубедить в ошибке, но сделать это можно только предъявив >сам источник правила. Буду искать. Спасибо!

Переубедить невозможно, если автор использует принятый в его профессии термин. А правило здесь может быть такое. Здесь "число" используется в значении (конкретное) количество, а такие слова относятся к категории несчетных (другое название - неисчисляемых) существительных, а они не имеют обычного множественного числа, только для специальных целей (ср. минеральные воды, авиационные керосины - это все сорта вещества).

Кое-что доступно изложенное по неисчислимым существительным вот здесь есть:
[Особенности образования форм множественного числа существительных | genon.ru](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=60f42b11-4207-40b6-b331-6d46d4aff25b)
Там все больше про вещественные, у нас немного другой случай. Но если будете искать - то в этом направлении, на "неисчислимые существительные", слово число в данном значении вполне к ним относится.

Сложность же здесь в том, что "число" в значении "цифра, некий набор цифровых символов используемых для счета", множественное число вполне себе имеет, что при использовании в тексте подписи под рисунком может вызвать двусмысленность. Ну, грубо говоря, разные источники, разные оценки дают разные *числа* - и вот распределение этих-то "чисел" якобы и показано на графике. 
Но показано-то на нем сосем другое...

Comment: Большое спасибо! Профессия с автором у нас одна, поэтому я уверена в том, что можно сказать лучше и правильнее. В комбинации этих слов единственно верный вариант тот, что предложен Sibylla. Это без вопросов. Обычно ещё пишется "Хронологическое распределение взрывов...". А переубеждать пытаюсь непосредственно правилами русского языка. Если их нет по данной теме, тогда делать нечего )). В данном случае пытаюсь найти, почему нельзя говорить "распределение чисел" событий или предметов во времени.

Comment: "Переубедить невозможно, если автор использует принятый в его профессии термин". Мой вопрос абсолютно не затрагивает профессиональные термины. А правила русского языка одни для всех. (моё мнение ))) )

Comment: *А правила русского языка одни для всех. (моё мнение* - так-то оно так, но профессионализмы являются частью русского языка и его правил соответственно. "Распределение чисел Маха" - это срвсем не то, что можно подумать о числе взрывов в обычном понимании.  Но коль чкоро Вы говорите с автором на одном языке, то продолжение этой темы неактуально. Я не против логики Sibylla, она мне вполне нравится, просто боялся, что здесь могут быть подводные камни.

Comment: Нет, профессионализмов здесь нет. Это обычное распределение, показывающее на графике, сколько в каком месяце было взрывов. Вот  и я удивляюсь, что кто-то ещё с уверенностью доказывает, что так писать можно. Подумала, может, я что-то не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: распределение ежемесячного числа взрывов.

Из словаря:

**ЧИСЛО**, -а; мн. числа, -сел, -слам; ср. 1. Единица счёта, выражающая то или иное количество. Дробное, целое, простое ч.  2. День месяца в порядковом ряду других дней. В первых числах августа. **3. Количество кого-, чего-л. В небольшом числе городов.**  4. Ряд, совокупность, состав кого-, чего-л. Быть в числе первых. 5. Лингв. Грамматическая категория.

**КОЛИЧЕСТВО**, -а; ср. 1. Категория, характеризующая предметы и явления внешнего мира со стороны величины, объёма, числа, степени развития. Ожидалось большое к. гостей.

Хотя сущ. "число" в общем случае имеет форму мн. числа, конкретно в данном значении оно соотносится с "количеством", а у этого слова формы мн. числа нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за вариант, но Вы не полностью ответили на вопрос. Можно ли говорить именно так, как написано в теме?

Comment: Нельзя так говорить, здесь  сущ "число" должно употребляться в ед. числе.

Comment: Спасибо! Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на источник, где это чётко указывается?

Comment: Конкретной ссылки у меня, к сожалению,  нет, а это просто вывод  из словарных статей, то есть доказательство того, что здесь нельзя использовать форму " числа". Эта форма используется в таких выражениях, как "в первых числах месяца", "целые и дробные числа".

Comment: Эх, мне нужно переубедить в ошибке, но сделать это можно только предъявив сам источник правила. Буду искать. Спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется, что такого правила нет,  но можно поискать материал в книгах " Речевые ошибки" или "Культура речи".

Comment: Прокомментировал в своем ответе.

Comment: А вот кстати, а где в списке значений всякого рода характеристические числа? Число Авогадро, число Маха - и много еще всяких-разных чисел?! Это явно не количество, о чем я и пытался предупредить... Это некая характеристика, как ни странно ближе всего из списка - лингвистическая категория. Это именно категория, характеристика, никоим образом  не лингвистическая конечно, а научно-техническая. Это глубокий оффтоп, размышления вслух, отвечать совершенно не обязательно.

Comment: Величина, число, количество - не так просто понять, как они соотносятся друг с другом. Но вот интересное определение для числа Авогадро, где встречаются эти три понятия:Число́ Авога́дро, конста́нта Авогадро, постоянная Авогадро — физическая ВЕЛИЧИНА, ЧИСЛЕННО равная КОЛИЧЕСТВУ специфицированных структурных единиц (атомов, молекул, ионов, электронов или любых других частиц) в 1 моле вещества.